# How to remove specific text from a value using apache nifi

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have a csv file and I need to remove somespecific text from a colum and replace another value for that.

My csv

```
date,name
20191106,sachith
```

To do it, I have used `UpdateRecord` processor with following configurations.

`/date` -> `${field:replaceAll(2019,1212)}`

**CSV-Reader**
[image: CSV-Reader]

**CSV-Record-Writer**
[image]

My current configurations makes following csv as result.

```
date,name
"",sachith
```

**Expected result**

```
date,name
12121106,sachith
```

What am I missing here? I have used `QueryRecord` processor, but it didnt solve my issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't confirm exactly what you have done without your full UpdateRecord config, but your Reader and Writer are 100% correct. To achieve your expected result you need to update your UpdateRecord config to the following:
[image]

I changed the Replacement Value Strategy to 'Record Path Value' and that allows me to populate the date field using the record path on the right hand side of the '/date' Dynamic property. More info on how to use Record Path here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html

An alternative solution, closer to your original config is:

[image]

The only thing you were missing was to refer to the field's value. More on that in the docs (if you click the Additional Details link) for UpdateRecord here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html

My mind jumped to Record Path a bit too fast, but both work!!

Please let me know if you encounter any further issues :)